# How to get all the *.sln files from a given directory using Groovy script?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, groovyshell, jenkins-groovy

Am writing a Jenkins Groovy script file to get all the .NET project solution files (`*.sln`) in a given directory (including subdirectories).

First I tried to get the list of directories in a given path. I used the below code which is working fine:

```
File folder = new File("D:\\Data");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

2) When modified the code as below to list out all the solution files in a given path I am getting error:

```
File folder = new File("D:\\Data");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
Collection files = FileUtils.listFiles(
  folder, 
  new RegexFileFilter("^(*.sln)"), 
  DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY
  );

for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].isFile()) {
        println("File " + files[i].getName());
        } 
    else if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
        println("Directory " + files[i].getName());
        }
    }
```

Error details:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 5: unable to resolve class RegexFileFilter 
 @ line 5, column 3.
     new RegexFileFilter("^(*.sln)"), 
     ^
```

Could anyone please help me on this to get all the solution files in a given path (including subdirectories)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "I'm getting error" - which error, what message?

Comment: please update your question with error StackTrace you get.

Comment: I guess it's `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils`, is it? If yes, why do you use a `RegexFileFilter` if there is a [`SuffixFileFilter`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/SuffixFileFilter.html) or even a [`listFiles(File directory, String[] extensions, boolean recursive)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String[],%20boolean))?

Comment: @ Vikrant Kashyap,@Thomas, Error details updated

Answer (score 2):

Simples solution is to use FileNameFinder like this:

```
def finder = new FileNameFinder()
def files = finder.getFileNames 'D:\\Data', '**/*.sln'
print files
```

Comment: This does not print the solution files in a given path

Comment: I have edited pattern - first one was searching only in root folder, in order to search subfolders you have to add ** part. - I'm not sure on windows do you need to use \ instead of / - my guess is not.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.*

def startDir = new File("D:\\Data")

startDir.eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
    if (it.name.endsWith('.sln')) {
        println it
    }
}
```